# Balance different groups of values in a dataframe in an equally spaced manner

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

```
ll = [['r']*5, ['sq']*3, ['r']*5, ['pu']*2, ['r']*5, ['dsp']*3, ['r']*5, ['l']*5, ['r']*5, ['dr']*3, ['r']*5, ['si']*4, ['r']*5,
    ['te']*2, ['r']*5, ['bc']*3, ['r']*5, ['lsr']*2, ['r']*5, ['jj'], ['r']*5,]
l = [item for sublist in ll for item in sublist]
df_l = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

The list ll is a simplified version of a time series list (time stamps are omitted here for simplification). It contains 11 unique elements.
I want to balance the elements, which means that all elements shall appear more or less equally frequent.

Example: As you can see, 'jj' appears only once. Therefore I want to reduce the other elements such that they appear only once, too. (In my actual case of application, no element appears only once. The least frequent element 'jj' appears 2000 times, while 'r' appears 170000 times. This here is just a representative simplification)

Since I am dealing with time series data, I cannot just randomly delete rows of the more frequent elements until all element groups are balanced, since this could destroy time series patterns. Instead, I want that the overrepresented entries are removed in an equally spaced manner (e.g.
if 'te' appears twice as often as 'jj', I want to delete every second row of 'te'. This assures that only the "resolution" of the time series patterns is reduced, but the patterns themselves remain.
How can I do this efficiently?

I would present my tries but I have no idea how to approach this.

Comment: Can you distill this a little more?  If you have `[a,bb,ccc,bb,dd,eeee]`, what would you expect the result to be

Comment: I would expect it to be like [a, b, c, b, d, e] in the end, since a is the least frequent element in your list, so all the other elements must be reduced to the original number of a.

Comment: Just to clarify: It boils down to 2 conditions: 1. Reduce the overrepresented groups of elements to the count of the least frequent element. 2. Reduce each overrepresented group by deleting its elements in an equally spaced way.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal? It same that you're trying to keep a pattern to analyze data to find out what the pattern is. This seems difficult to achieve. A bit context on the real goal might be useful.

Comment: I want to pass the data into a Convolutional Neural Network. If the data is unbalanced, CNNs overfit on the overrepresented groups. Therefore the balancing. The other challenge (the reduction of the groups of overrepresented elements in an equally spaced way) shall avoid that e.g.  in the sequence of 3000 consecutive 'l', a big part of the first 500 is deleted, while the last 500 might remain untouched. This could distort the time series patterns.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
s = df[0]  # Whatever the series actually is

# Group the rows into sets of consecutive duplicates
groups = [g for _,g in df.groupby((s != s.shift()).cumsum())]

# Find the smallest group of consecutive values
n = min(len(g) for g in groups)

# Trim each group to that size and stack them into a new DataFrame
df2 = pd.concat((g[:n] for g in groups), ignore_index=True)
```

For your data, the result is:

```
0     r
1    sq
2     r
3    pu
4     r
5   dsp
6     r
7     l
8     r
9    dr
10    r
11   si
12    r
13   te
14    r
15   bc
16    r
17  lsr
18    r
19   jj
20    r
```

*Sidenote:* While it seems like it might do what you're asking, I just want to point out that the representation/relative frequency of the distinct values is completely lost.

A better solution might be to reduce each group by the same "percentage".  So if the smallest group is 3, instead of reducing each group to 3 items, you'd reduce all groups to 1/3 of their size.  Or maybe that *is* what you're looking for...

Comment: Could you explain your sidenote, please? I do not seem to understand what you mean.

Comment: Sure, consider `[aaa,bbbbbbbbb,cccccc,bbbbbbbbb]` -- using the approach in the answer, the result would be `[aaa,bbb,ccc,bbb]` (each group trimmed to 3 occurrences), but a more representative result might be `[a,bbb,cc,bbb]` (each group reduced to 1/3 of its initial size).  In the latter, there are still twice as many `c`s as `a`s, (for example) preserving the relative frequency of the occurrences.  This raises other questions, however, about how to handle rounding and what to do if the smallest group is _already_ of size 1.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess, there is no need for the "percentage"-approach. I will try your solution from above and see if it works on the real data.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a problem with the approach you posted: As you can see in my list above, there are multiple sequences of 'r'. Your approach considers each sequence as an individual element group, rather than considering it as one group. Therefore, it does not work on my actual case of application.

Comment: @lonyen11 I based that off of your answer to how `[a,bb,ccc,bb,dd,eeee]` should be processed (you said `[a, b, c, b, d, e]`).  If both statements are true, I'm confused.  Can you explain the distinction?

Comment: I am sorry. I missed out on the second sequence of b's that you gave in the example. So, your approach is indeed right for the example. Thank you! I also found a solution with respect to my original case of application, which partly makes use of your solution. Sorry for the mess.